# Spagobi collaboration issue in analytical dossier

Tags: collaboration, spagobi, dossier

i have created a dossier document in Spagobi Tool. My presentation template contains 2 slides and i have created 2 task nodes accordingly in the workflow process. 
   When i execute my dossier document on the server it is throwing an error stating "Some problems have occurs while starting collaboration process".
   Following is the workflow process definition i have submitted in the template build on the server.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<process-definition
  xmlns="http://jbpm.org/3/jpdl"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://jbpm.org/3/jpdl http://jbpm.org/xsd/jpdl-3.0.xsd"
  name="BookletWorkflowProcess">
   <swimlane name="/spagobi/admin">
      <assignment class="it.eng.spagobi.booklets.assignmenthandlers.SpagoBISwimlaneAssignment"></assignment>
   </swimlane>
   <swimlane name="/spagobi/dev">
      <assignment class="it.eng.spagobi.booklets.assignmenthandlers.SpagoBISwimlaneAssignment"></assignment>
   </swimlane>
   <swimlane name="/spagobi/test">
      <assignment class="it.eng.spagobi.booklets.assignmenthandlers.SpagoBISwimlaneAssignment"></assignment>
   </swimlane>
   <start-state name="start">
      <transition name="" to="ProcessOOTemplate"></transition>
   </start-state>
   <node name="ProcessOOTemplate">
      <transition name="" to="fork1"></transition>
      <event type="node-enter"> 
         <action name="process_ootemplate_action" class="it.eng.spagobi.booklets.automatictasks.ProcessOOTemplateAction"></action>
      </event>
   </node>
   <fork name="fork1">
      <transition name="toaddnote1" to="AddNote1"></transition>
      <transition name="toaddnote2" to="AddNote2"></transition>
   </fork>
   <task-node name="AddNote1">
      <task name="add_note_task1" swimlane="/spagobi/dev">
         <event type="task-create">
         <script>
            <expression>
                taskInstance.setVariableLocally("spago_handler", "AddNoteHandler");
                taskInstance.setVariableLocally("spagobi_booklet_pageindex", "1");
            </expression>
        </script>
         </event>
      </task>
      <transition name="" to="join1"></transition>
   </task-node>
   <task-node name="AddNote2">
      <task name="add_note_task2" swimlane="/spagobi/test">
        <event type="task-create">
         <script>
            <expression>
                taskInstance.setVariableLocally("spago_handler", "AddNoteHandler");
                taskInstance.setVariableLocally("spagobi_booklet_pageindex", "2");
            </expression>
        </script>
         </event>
      </task>
      <transition name="" to="join1"></transition>
   </task-node>
   <join name="join1">
      <transition name="" to="GenerateFinalDocument"></transition>
   </join>
   <node name="GenerateFinalDocument">
      <transition name="" to="ValidateFinalDocument"></transition>
      <event type="node-enter">
         <action name="generate_final_document_action" class="it.eng.spagobi.booklets.automatictasks.GenerateFinalDocumentAction"></action>
      </event>
   </node>
   <end-state name="end1"></end-state>
   <task-node name="ValidateFinalDocument">
      <task name="validate_document_task" swimlane="/spagobi/admin">
        <event type="task-create">
         <script>
            <expression>
                taskInstance.setVariableLocally("spago_handler", "ValidateFinalDocumentHandler");
            </expression>
         </script>
        </event>
      </task>
      <transition name="" to="end1"></transition>
   </task-node>
</process-definition>
```

Can someone help me find the roots to this issue and possible solutions if any?